# Cookie newbie php

Tags: php, cookies

I want to make a contact form that will show the name, gender and comments when I click submit.

Right now I'm not really sure how to retrieve the value from my form and put it in a cookie, so it will dissapear when I refresh.

My code:

```
  <body> 

    $name = $gender = $comment = "";

    setcookie("name", $name, time() + 100);

    if(isset($_COOKIE["name"]))
    {
        $name = $_COOKIE["name"];
    }
    else
    {
        $name = " ";
    }


        ?>

        <h2>Comment formulier</h2>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
               Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
               <br><br>
               Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
               <br><br>
               Gender:
               <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?>  value="female">Female
               <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?>  value="male">Male
               <br><br>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
            </form>

        <?php
        echo "<h2>Comments:</h2>";
        echo $name;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $comment;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $gender;
        ?>

        </body>
```

Please excuse me for this very newbie question, I just started learning PHP 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

First you are not set you coockie. Do it with setcookie("name"); function. Then you can retreive it with $_COOKIE['name']; function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot a `<?php` tag.

This should do the trick:

```
<body> 

<?php // <---

$name = $gender = $comment = "";

setcookie("name", $name, time() + 100);

if(isset($_COOKIE["name"]))
{
    $name = $_COOKIE["name"];
}
else
{
    $name = " ";
}


?>
```